# Need to create an <input()> function that responds to either stdin or a serial port

Tags: python-3.7

I am using a PC with Python to control an ASCII API through a serial connection to a micro.
The Python code sends commands to the API as a result of Keyboard events.

I need to extend input() - or write a new version - that monitors the serial
connection "simultaneously". In this way a process on the micro serial connection can signal the python code and cause an event in the same way a key command on the PC causes an event.
Since input() stops code execution until (string + \n), input() needs to be
extended.

I have a working serial connection to the micro API.

I am clueless how to do this.

Things I've tried are too embarrassing to show.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the problem at best. However from what I understand you would like to change the input () function to your liking. Something like this can be done, even if it represents a rough solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov  4 20:16:13 2019

@author: Roberto Bellarosa
"""

import builtins

def fake_input(prompt):
    print(prompt)
    return "trgy"

builtins.input = fake_input

name = input("Enter your name >")

print("Hello,"+name+"!")
```

Comment: Hello Robert and thx for responding. That looks like C function pointers... OK and that could be part of a solution. But really the problem is "I need to monitor TWO serial inputs - either of which could send". Probably need try: except: and timeout?